# Plotting Smith chart using PySmithPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot Smith chart in python using PySmithPlot, it has to be placed along some other items in frame, but i can't find a way to do so. 
I have managed to make plots with matplotlib, but didn't have any luck so far with Smiths chart. Can anyone give me a reference to a site where i could find explanation to my problem?

```
import matplotlib as mp
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import style
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import Tk, W, E
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style, Entry
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import smithplot
from smithplot import SmithAxes
mp.use("TkAgg")
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
class Dizajn(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "title")
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frames = {}
    for F in (Home, FirstPage):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(Home)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, cont):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ax = f.add_subplot(111, projection="smith")
        pl.show()
        self.grid()

app = Dizajn()
app.mainloop()
```

And this is the last line of error report
in transform_path_non_affine
NotImplementedError: Value for 'path_interpolation' cannot be interpreted.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a minimal working example with 1) how you plot your (individual) Smith charts, 2) in what kind of "frames" (?) you would like to put it in?

Comment: @Bart from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

fig = PLT.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot([(7, 2), (5, 3)], [(1, 6), (9, 5)])

PLT.show() 
I have tried adapting this code to display a Smith chart, but since i'm new to whole story i couldn't manage it. I have ploted matplotlib graphs because there are plenty of examples online, but i can't find anything that would help me understand how to plot a Smith graph... My frames are created using tkinter.

Comment: Sorry for complaining so much, but perhaps read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There is a huge amount of `imports` in your example which are not used, it looks like its a copy-paste from a larger code, but in its current form doesn't do anything (e.g., where is your `class Home()` initialised? Sorry, but there is little I can do with this.....

Comment: @Bart i have pasted the rest of code connected to the error, and left out things that are other elements of GUI like buttons etc... I hope this is enough, all of the imports are used, but i've cut out the parts where the code is irelevant for understanding my error.

Comment: @Bart i have managed to place graph. I'm very thankful for your help, couldn't have done it without you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PySmithPlot` provides a new `projection` which you can pass to e.g. `subplot()` or `add_subplot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl 
import smithplot
from smithplot import SmithAxes

fig = pl.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121) 
ax1.plot([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)]) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='smith') 
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I already have figure created like this
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
Since i'm unsure what that line exactly does, could you explain how am i supposed to show Smith char on my frame?

Comment: I have tried 
ax = f.add_subplot(211, projection="smith")
ax.plot([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)])
pl.show()

Comment: Yes, that should be it.... But I guess it doesn't work? It would be useful if you updated your initial question/post, include your/my minimal example there, and if the code doesn't work, show what goes wrong (resulting figure), which error messages you get, et cetera. I can't see from here what is happening on your screen :-)

Comment: Ok, as you can tell i am new to whole story so i will try to post relevant code and edit my original post in min.